# Why does accessing 'promise' directly not work after using await with fetch and response.json()?"

Tags: javascript, async-await

i am having confusion about the state of the promise after using await keyword
here's the code with the correct data
`

```
 async function myFunc(){
    try{

        const response=await fetch(
            "https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/apis/fetching-data/can-store/products.json"
            )
            
            if(!(response.ok)){
                throw new error(`HTTP Error ${response.status}`);
            }
            
            const data=await response.json();
            console.log(data[9].name);
            
        }
    catch(error){
        console.error(`could not get products: ${error}`);
    }

    finally{
        console.log("THANK YOU !!!!");
    }

}
myFunc();
```

This correctly outpus the data[9], but if i use the return data statement after this it doesnt work , heres the relevant code

```
async function fetchProducts() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/apis/fetching-data/can-store/products.json",
    );
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error: ${response.status}`);
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Could not get products: ${error}`);
  }
}

const promise = fetchProducts();
console.log(promise[0].name); // "promise" is a Promise object, so this will not work
```

But if i use this at the end , it works

```
const promise = fetchProducts();
promise.then((data) => console.log(data[0].name));
```

my confusion is if the await keyword at the beginning is there to resolve the promise then why do we have to again use (.then) outside the function to wait for the promise to resolve

I tried using chatgpt for the answers but didn't get a satisfactory explanation , also i have been using mdn web docs and the code is an example on the website , here's the link to the artcie .

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises

Comment: TL;DR - by their very nature, `async` functions return a `Promise` - that is ALL they ever return

Comment: `await` does not "resolve" the promise, the promise resolves on its own. `await` just waits for that to happen, by suspending (stopping) **the current function** code. It doesn't stop the entire world, or the code outside the function that called it - instead the `async` function returns a promise itself, and resolves it when completing its code evaluation.